# Error in connection database using pdo

Tags: php

I change the simple SQL query to pdo.now when I click on the log in button I got this error:

> Undefined variable: row in /var/www/login.php on line 16
>   Notice: Undefined variable: result in /var/www/login.php on line 17
>   Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/login.php on line 17 Your Login Name or Password is invalid

Code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','5');
    include("conn.php");
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // username and password sent from Form
        $u_name=addslashes($_POST['username']);
        $password=addslashes($_POST['password']);

        $sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$u_name' and password='$password'";
        $q   = $conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");
        $r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $active=$row['active'];
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);


        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1)
        {
            session_register("u_name");
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$u_name;
            header("location: main.php");
        }
        else
        {
              echo ("Your Login Name or Password is invalid");
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: I cannot see that you are assigning the $result variable anywhere!?

Comment: You can't use both PDO and mysql on the same query.

Comment: Not related, but since you're using PDO you can (and should) also use prepared statements in place of ```addslashes()```.

Comment: ya i konw can u tell me how should i count my row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_num_rows` is a function, that is a part of the *deprecated* `mysql_*` extension. Just check the PDO manual [here](http://www.php.net/pdo), and see how you can get the num-rows using PDO. You simply *cannot* use PDO and `mysql(i)_*` all together willy-nilly

You have many, many other issues in your code, including the query itself: `SELECT id FROM` will return a resultset in which each row has but a single column, called ID, but you go on to access `$row['active'];` in your code. That will issue a notice, because the index cannot be found.
Change the query to select all fields you actually do require `SELECT id, active FROM...` is the bare minimum, based on your code here.

Besides that, you're also wildly inconsistent as far as variable names go. What you call `$r` changes to `$row` the very next line... that's what's causing the `undefined variable` notices, of course.

You also have an injection vulnerability that is quite substantial, Here's how I'd query your data:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, active FROM admin where username = :user AND password = :pass');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username'],
    ':pass' => $_POST['password']
));
//$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount(); <-- only for update, delete or insert queries
$rowCount = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    ++$rowCount;//count while fetching
    //process row
}
//or
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rowCount = count($rows);
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    //process row
}
```

That said, you really should learn about prepared statements and ***hash your passwords***

Comment: thnks.Can u suggest me any site for this

Comment: @Mihirshah: for what? prepared statements: it's all in the linked manual page on php.net: `PDO::prepare`, `PDOStatement::execute`, `PDOStatement::rowCount` and `PDOStatement::fetch` are all the methods. On password hashing: just google PHP hash password (or check the `password_hash` function, if your PHP version permits it)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() in /var/www/login.php on line 14

Comment: @Mihirshah: Updated... please, read the docs I linked too, you could've figured it out yourself if you did

Comment: @Mihirshah: NP, please, do read the help section of this site: you are asked _not_ to post _"Thank you"_ comments, but instead resort to accepting answers (marking them as accepted by clicking the big check icon next to the answer). As a bonus: you'll be awarded 2 reputation points if you do

Answer (score 1):

The  `$r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` should be  `$row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Also, the `session_register()` function is deprecated. You shouldn't be using that.